# "{...} is not a function" although never called as a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

If I create a JSON object immediately before an anonymous function call, I get `TypeError: ({x:0, y:0}) is not a function` in Firefox, or `Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)} is not a function` in Chrome.

However, I never called `a` as a function. Also, when I put a semicolon after the object definition, this error does not occur.

According to http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons I don't see why I would, in theory, need a semicolon there. However, for some reason it is still required. Why?

```js
let a = { x: 0, y: 0 }

(() => {
    console.log('test')
})()
```

Comment: Just always use semicolons. You just gave a good example why you shouldn't omit them.

Comment: I'm usually following the NPM coding style (https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style.html), which explicitly states that I should never use semicolons except necessary. Also, even if I decided that I'm going to use them in the future, I would love to know, why the interpreter does not like what I did.

Comment: it cannot be emphasized enough. always use semicolons!!!!!

Comment: @Benni this is a situation when it would be considered "necessary" anyway just always use them

Comment: Specifically, that guide states _"In front of a leading ( or [ at the start of the line. This prevents the expression from being interpreted as a function call or property access, respectively."_ which is the situation you have right here. The opening paren causes the interpreter to read it as a function call.

Comment: @benni: i guess you missed one of the cars where you did always use them: "In front of a leading ( or [ at the start of the line. This prevents the expression from being interpreted as a function call or property access, respectively."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other's have said, the two statements are being read as a single, non-sensical statement. My peeve here is that no-one has properly answered **why** this happens here and not in other cases.

You quote the NPM style guide here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style.html
It says

> In front of a leading ( or [ at the start of the line. This prevents the expression from being interpreted as a function call or property access, respectively.

So your issue is because the second statement starts with `(` or `[`, and this confuses the parser. In these cases a semi-colon is needed. **Why would the parser be confused** by `(` or `[`? Because for instance `{ x: 0, y: 0}["x"]` would be valid code. And the same for `{ x: 0, y: 0}()`, it's perfectly valid, it will just crash. But the parser cannot know if it makes sense or not, it has to apply the same rules everywhere.

Note that the npm style guide then says to put the semi-colon on the line with the `(` in cases like this. So you would write:

```
let a = { x: 0, y: 0 }

;(() => { // semi-colon at start of this line
    console.log('test')
})()
```

The reason for this is that if you were to put it after the first statement and later edit your code, you would re-introduce the problem. For instance end up like this:

```
let a = { x: 0, y: 0 };

let b = { x: 1, y: 1 }

(() => { // this will fail
    console.log('test')
})()
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't terminated your assignment to `x`, so the engine is seeing you call a function:

```
// Wrong:
let {x: 0, y:}()();
```

You should use semi-colon to terminate:

```js
let a = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // terminate this line with a semi-colon ;

(() => {
    console.log('test')
})()
```

The reason why is, without the semi-colon, the two statements will be read as one, 
 in turn making no sense.

Comment: @Matsemann was this meant to be on the other answer - this one actually explains the need for the semi colon as was the question by the OP and I don't see how it should be closed as a typo when OP is specifically asking about why there is the need for the colon

Comment: (The post is edited now) But why would the two statements be read as one here, but not if it was `42\n"hello"`. That's the question, everyone understands it's being read as two statements, the interesting part is why in some cases and not in others.

Comment: @Matsemann Excuse me? "rep farming"..? You might think and work that way, but i don't. It not simply a typo error - if you bother to read OPs question - it is _why_ semi-colon is required. Please keep your unwitting angst for somewhere else.

Comment: > "if you bother to read OPs question - it is why semi-colon is required."
Exactly, I did read the question and pointed out that you didn't answer it, at least not before editing.

Answer (score 0):

instead raises a TypeError, JavaScript tries to interpret it as

```
let a = { x: 0, y: 0 }(
    () => {console.log('test')}
)()
```

Details refer to:
https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion/

Answer (score 0):

Always use semicolon ,since Javascript compiler compile the code line by line from top to bottom ,so in your case it is interpreted as

```js
let a = { x: 0, y: 0 } (() => { console.log('test') })()
```

and compiler is unable to determine where the line terminates and also the func is  executed at the same time which makes no sense to the compiler.
That's why you are getting TypeError as you mentioned.

To fix this use semicolon after defining your object like this

```js
let a = { x: 0, y: 0 } ;
(() =>  console.log('test') )();
```

You can also remove curly braces to refactor your code (just a little advice) since your function is not returning any value (using es6 property).